# How to generate WSDL from class (not webservice)

Tags: c#, wsdl

I'm working on my diploma thesis based on multi agent systems and I need to generate WSDL from ontology (i.e. from class that is not webservice, no `[WebService]` or `[ServiceContract]` annotation).

Information that I have:

- List of classes that represents operations (I can't change them)

How to generate own WSDL without stuff like a classes with annotation `[WebService]` or `[ServiceContract]`?

Note: I can't use anotations because the whole solution is something like a Gateway between Agents in Multi-Agent systems and webservices. Each new agent in Multi-Agent system can be accessbile through SOAP (webservice). I've already implemented IHTTPHandler that is responsible for serialization SOAP messages to objects. So solution looks like a webservice but inside is my own IHTTPHandler.

Comment: Why you can't go with annotation?

Answer (score 3):

Seems you'll need to go through [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28VS.80%29.aspx) to inspect your classes and to build a WSDL contract as a XML document, from scratch.